# Using Dictionaries(similar to Python dict)

Tags: python, dictionary, plsql, associative-array, in-memory

I want to create a dictionary object in plsql. (11g)
Dictionary object will have three fields: employee_id, manager_id, duration
I do not want to create table because of the query times. I want to access items in the ram.

I will insert 2 millions rows into this dictionary object by using bulk collect. 
Then I want to access dictionay object like :(334 is employee id)
   dictEmp[334].manager_id=8
or return dictEmp[334].duration

Can you suggest any document?
Thanks

Comment: Looks an awful lot like a job for a [temporary table](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_temporary_tables_sql.htm).

Comment: Create `dict` maps for your objects for each index you need and be on your marry way. Don't over-complicate it with additional structures as you ain't gonna get a better performance then native Python `dict` lookup.

Comment: Something like [this](https://repl.it/IRaL/2)?

Comment: Sounds like an [associative array](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99969) in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an associative array in PL/SQL.

```
declare 
    type employee_t is table of emp_demo%rowtype index by pls_integer;
    l_employees employee_t;
begin
    for r in (
        select * from emp_demo
    )
    loop
        l_employees(r.employee_id) := r;
    end loop;

    dbms_output.put_line('Manager for employee 334 is: ' || l_employees(334).manager_id);

    dbms_output.put_line('Manager''s manager is ' || l_employees(l_employees(334).manager_id).employee_name);
end;
```

Test data:

```
create table emp_demo
( employee_id integer primary key
, employee_name varchar2(40)
, manager_id  integer
, hiredate date
, duration integer );

insert all
    into emp_demo values (8, 'Clark', 5, date '2015-04-02', 18)
    into emp_demo values (334, 'Jones', 8, date '2015-01-05', 12)
    into emp_demo values (455, 'Smith', 7, date '2015-02-04', 14)
    into emp_demo values (566, 'Patel', 6, date '2015-03-03', 16)
select * from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Let say you can iterate a list of lists (called employees) with columns [employee_id, manager_id, duration]:

```
desired_dict = {}
for employee_id, manager_id, duration in employees:
     desired_dict[employee_id] = {"manager_id" : manager_id, "duration" : duration }

#or even better
desired_dict = {employee_id : {"manager_id" : manager_id, "duration" : duration } 
for employee_id, manager_id, duration in employees}

#now, you can access an  employee like:
some_manager = desired_dict[334]['manager_id']
some_duration = desired_dict[334]['duration']
```

But you probably want to use something like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/)
and do something like:

```
import pandas as pd
employees_data = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns=['employee_id', 'manager_id', 'duration'])
employees_data.index = employees_data['employee_id']
desired_dict = employees_data.to_dict()
```

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding. want to implement python dict structure in oracle plsql